# How to associate my new android app to open Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working on app which uses GoogleMapV2 api. I will get my coordinates from Whatsapp. When I try to open the coordinates, list of apps are coming for opening Mapdata (Chrome, Google Maps, Firefox). 
[image]
How can I show my App to be in that list which handles map data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this intent filter in your manifest, within the activity tag

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="geo" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```